# Migrating from Oracle JDK8 to Open jdk11, looking for rmi replacement

Tags: java, glassfish, rmi, corba, iiop

I'm migrating from Oracle JDK8 to OpenJDK11. I am facing problem with exportObject(new Myobj) call.

As rmi is removed in jdk11, I am using glassfish jars for PortableRemoteObject usage to export and lookup remote objects

I am using below jars from glassfish to get missing classes in openjdk11.

- glassfish-corba-omgapi
- glassfish-corba-orb
- javax.transaction.api
- pfl-dynamic
- pfl-basic
- glassfish-corba-internal-api
- pfl-tf.jar

I am expecting javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.PortableRemoteObject.exportObject() to work as is in JDK8. But I am getting below error. I tried to use  com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObjet and also com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject from glassfish jars. But still facing same error.

java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: object not exported        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.toStub(MyClass.java:18)        at javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.toStub(PortableRemoteObject.java:132)

Ant task for RMIC

```
<!-- Ant task for RMIC -->  
   <target name="rmic">
    <taskdef name="rmic"
             classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Rmic" />
    <rmic classname="com.MyRmiImpl"
          base="${classes.dir}"
          classpathref="javac.classpath" />
  </target>
```

public class MyNode  {

```
static Registry registry;

public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

        registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(3322);
        MyRmiImpl remoteImpl = new MyRmiImpl();
        PortableRemoteObject.exportObject(remoteImpl); 
        Remote objStub = PortableRemoteObject.toStub(remoteImpl);// getting exception at this line 
        registry.rebind("MyRmiInterface", objStub);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: [RMI is **not** removed from JDK 11](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=en/java/javase/11/core&id=RMIUG-GUID-70825E99-57CF-470F-871A-5CCB6C2771BE).

Comment: How did you resolve this?

Comment: @donlys Resolve what? There is no problem to resolve. The link I provided proves it.

Comment: And here is the [OpenJDK 11 RMI Javadoc link](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/11/spec/pfd/java-se-11-pfd-spec/api/java.rmi/module-summary.html). It is also [present in OpenJDK 12](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/12/latestSpec/api/java.rmi/module-summary.html). I don't know what you people are talking about. @donlys

Comment: My question is how do I rewrite existing code that is using PortableRemoteObject.narrow

Comment: @Donlys Rerwite it why? NB This question is based on a complete misunderstanding of the error message. `NoSuchObjectException` refers to a stub expiry, not to a complete removal of an API from the JDK, and it relies on code that is basically meaningless in the first place, being a mixture of RMI/JRMP and RMI/IIOP. You should ask your question, whatever it is, in a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in the comments, `javax.rmi` did not get removed from JDK 11 but CORBA and RMI-IIOP did get removed. The result is `javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject` is no longer available from the JDK.

If you only needed the `PortableRemoteObject.narrow` method for checking type, you might be able to replace it with a cast as shown in this [diff](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/jackrabbit/trunk/jackrabbit-jcr-tests/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/test/JNDIRepositoryStub.java?r1=1836349&r2=1836348&pathrev=1836349).

Otherwise look into [Glassfish](https://dev.to/dbh/java-11-making-rmi-calls-and-ejbs-work-again-1l5b) for your CORBA needs.

```
implementation group: 'org.glassfish.corba', name: 'glassfish-corba-orb', version: '4.2.0'
```